# Implementing Gedit style fullscreen HeaderBar

Tags: python, gtk3, gedit, gobject

I am working on a **Gtk+ 3** application that is likely to be used fullscreen most of the time, but needs to be switched between fullscreen and non-fullscreen, while maintaining access to the controls located in the header bar. The problem is, since the headerbar is part of the window decorations, it gets hidden when the window goes fullscreen.

My current kludge so ensure the controls are always available works like this:

**Setup**

- create a `Gtk.Window` with vertical `Gtk.Box` as first child
- create a custom `Gtk.HeaderBar` (w/ added full screen togglebutton)
- set window's titlebar as my custom `Gtk.HeaderBar`
- add all the window's content to the `Gtk.Box`

**When window goes fullscreen**

- remove the `Gtk.HeaderBar` from the `Gtk.Window` titlebar
- pack the `Gtk.HeaderBar` into the `Gtk.Box` (window's first child).
  This results in the `Gtk.HeaderBar` being at the bottom of the window, so
- re-position the `Gtk.HeaderBar` to the top of the `Gtk.Box`

**When the window goes un-fullscreen**

- remove the `Gtk.HeaderBar` from the `gtk.Box`
- set it as the `Gtk.Window`'s titlebar
  This results in the following **Gtk-warning**: `gtk_window_set_titlebar() called on a realized window` (who cares, just a warning)

This works, but it seems like very much of a hack, and more complicated than it should have to be. Am I missing something and there is a more straightforward approach?

I know several Gtk+ 3 based apps have the header bar behavior I am after (gedit for example), but I have not been able to determine how that is implemented. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Also, here is a GitHub gist with a full working example of my current hacky solution: https://gist.github.com/KurtJacobson/6b045b6fc38907a2f18c38f6de2929e3

I will accept answers in any (programming) language.

Comment: That behavior must be implemented. Check https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/master/gedit/gedit-window.c on how they do it.

Comment: Ok, it looks like they have two `Gtk.HeaderBars`, one as the actual window titlebar, and another in a reliever in a `Gtk.Overlay` that gets shown when the window goes full-screen. Thank you.